# Picasso 2.5.2 does not load a local image

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso, okhttp

I am using Picasso 2.5.2 to use it with OkHttp 2.5.0
The code in `onCreate()` is like below:

```
 File mypath = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+ date + "image.png");
        if (mypath.exists())
        {
            Picasso.with(FullscreenImage.this).load(mypath).into(fullImage);
            Toasty.info(FullscreenImage.this, mypath.toString()).show();
        }
        else
        {
             // Download the image from Firebase and create the image in the 
             //  same directory and name
        }
```

I see the image in the `files` folder in my app folder but it does not display in the image view.
The image size: 1.4 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by turning the file into a bitmap then use it in the ImageView:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mypath.toString());
            fullImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is stuck like me, I did like this, checking on the Picasso webpage (
https://square.github.io/picasso/  ) - section RESOURCE LOADING, line 3:

```
String drPath = localData[position].getDrawablePath();

if(!drPath.equals(""))
{
    var f = **new File(context.getFilesDir(), drPath)**;
    try
    {
        Picasso.get()
               .load(f)
               .fit()
               .centerCrop()
               .into(holder.itemImage);
    }
 }
```

previously copied the file from Uri to local position like this:

```
     try {
    
         File f = new File(CategoryFragment.this
.getContext()
.getFilesDir()
, fileName);
         f.setWritable(true, false);
         OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int length = 0;
    
         while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
             outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
         }
    
         outputStream.close();
         inputStream.close();
```

registered ONLY THE NAME OF THE FILE like this:                                                                 `cmdEditVM.setDrawable(***fileName***, positionForNewDrawable);`

It had been retrieved from the Uri with the following (taken from SO):

```
public String getFileName (Uri uri)
{
    String result = null;
    if (uri.getScheme().equals("content"))
    {
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        try
        {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                if (columnIndex >= 0) {result = cursor.getString(columnIndex);}
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cursor != null) {cursor.close();}
        }
    }
    if (result == null)
    {
        result = uri.getPath();
        int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (cut != -1)
        {
            result = result.substring(cut + 1);
        }
    }
    
    
    return result;
}
```